# Need to write to db from validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my model I have custom validation method that sends request to the external service. Based on the response I add errors to `errors` array if any.

If there are errors, I also need to create new records of `ErrorLog` models, which represents error log. The problem is that when validation fails, it performs `ROLLBACK` on database, and all my new `ErrorLog` records are lost. What is the best way to implement it?

I also should say that `after_rollback` is not called for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`after_rollback` is only called on objects that are saved or destroyed during the transaction. Are you setting up the `after_rollback` callback on your main class or on your `ErrorLog` class?

In fact, using the `after_rollback` callback on your `ErrorLog` class would seem to be the easiest approach. The only case where you're going to lose the `ErrorLog` instances is if the transaction is rolled back so something like this should work:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :check_external

  def check_external
    unless external_says_i_am_okay?
      ErrorLog.create!(:message => 'oops')
    end
  end
end

class ErrorLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_rollback :save_anyway

  def save_anyway
    self.save!
  end
end
```

Of course having said all that you might want to consider the performance of getting an external service to validate your models. It might not be sufficiently quick if you're creating objects in the scope of a web request for example. You'd also want to make sure that the `ErrorLog#save` wouldn't fail as you're going to be outside the scope of a transaction by that point.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I understand my mistake and set up  `after_rollback` inside `ErrorLog` model. But `self.save!` don't do anything. I have `SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN \n SQL (0.1ms)  COMMIT` in the log, without any insertations.

Comment: I wonder if it thinks it is already saved because it was 'saved' in the transaction itself. You might want to try calling `touch` on it or changing an attribute to see if that nudges the save into life. Worth checking too that the callback is definitely being called by logged in there.

Comment: Only with ErrorLog.create!(self.attributes) I can acheive that error has been saved. It looks like dirty hack, but I don't know, what else to do. Thanks for help.